# Laravel taking so long to process any request

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, wampserver

I just installed Laravel 5.4 following the installation instructions from Laravel website. I'm using Windows 10 with Wamp64 installation. After installing Laravel and configuring my Apache with proper Virtual Hosts I opened Google Chrome to try it and the request took more than 10 seconds. I updated the page and it took more than 10 seconds again. I found online that I could optimize the time using the following commands:
    php artisan route:cache
    php artisan config:cache
    php artisan optimize
However, it didn't change anything and the request still takes more than 10 seconds to be replied.
Anyone out there with the same issue? Any thoughts how to solve it?

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs for any warnings or errors?  What is your script doing?

Comment: My script is doing nothing but showing the default Laravel page of a fresh Laravel installation. From my Apache access log I got: 
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2017:03:33:16 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2321
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2017:03:33:33 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
That shows that my GET request is waiting 17 seconds from a reply.

Comment: could be a lot of stuff. usually it's a problem of your local infrastructure. Actually i have a similar issue (less extreme than yours) where i have xampp on one machine which is running totally fine and on another it is super slow. Same version. Both windows 10. Best guess is that the address accnot be resolved (or super slow) - do you use a virtualhost locally? Do you use localhost? try to access localhost via IP directly.

Comment: If you are using `Laravel`'s scaffolding `app.css` style sheet then check your internet connection.  Because it requires `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600`

Comment: I'm using virtualhost locally. It doesn't matter if I use the virtualhost name or the localhost to access the page it still takes more than 10 seconds to respond. I tried: http://127.0.0.1/subdrivewebdatalogger/public/ and it took a long time to respond. I have Internet access and I'm not using virtual machine.